# Unable to fetch certain data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I want to extract the table data using beautifulsoup4 in Python which is under "Saturday, May 24" from this web page.

http://www.afl.com.au/fixture?roundId=CD_R201401410#tround

screen shot:

[image]

From the above screen shot it is clear that I need to extract all Preview hyperlinks under the date Saturday, May 24.

Please help me out.

I tried this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys
lPreviewLinkList = []
lLink = "http://www.afl.com.au/fixture?roundId=CD_R201401410#tround"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req_for_players = urllib2.Request(lLink,headers=header)
page_for_players = urllib2.urlopen(req_for_players)
soup_for_players = BeautifulSoup(page_for_players)

table_for_players = soup_for_players.find("table", { "class" : "fancy-zebra fixture" })
for row in table_for_players.find_all("tbody"):
    for cell in row.find_all("th"):
        lCellValue = cell.get_text()
        #print lCellValue
    for cell in row.find_all("li"):
        lCellValue = cell.get_text()
        if lCellValue == "Preview":
            for link in cell.find_all('a'):
                lPreviewLinkList.append("http://www.afl.com.au/" + link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Yep, and what have you tried?

Comment: I have mentioned my code

Comment: And what's not working?

Comment: Please provide an error description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys
lPreviewLinkList = []
bCapture = False
lLink = "http://www.afl.com.au/fixture?roundId=CD_R201401410#tround"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req_for_players = urllib2.Request(lLink,headers=header)
page_for_players = urllib2.urlopen(req_for_players)
soup_for_players = BeautifulSoup(page_for_players)

table_for_players = soup_for_players.find("table", { "class" : "fancy-zebra fixture" })
for row in table_for_players.findAll("tr"):
    for dateRow in row.findAll("th", {"colspan" : "4"}):
        bCapture = True if dateRow.text == "Saturday, May 24" else False
    if bCapture:
        for infoRow in row.findAll("td", {"class": "info"}):
            for link in infoRow.findAll("a", {"class" : "preview"}):
                lPreviewLinkList.append("http://www.afl.com.au/" + link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. great effort. :)